# Locating and using Full Motion Video (FMV) toolbox for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, installation, arcgis-full-motion-video

I've just installed version 1.2 of the [Full Motion Video Add-In](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/06/04/the-arcgis-full-motion-video-add-in-1-2-is-available-for-download/), along with the new geoprocessing toolbox. After running the installation for the tools, it creates a folder on the C drive but does not contain a toolbox. There is no link from the FMV Video Manager pane to the toolbox, nor does it appear in the system toolboxes. I tried to "Add Toolbox" and looked in all the normal places (Documents, Users, C drive etc) and came up empty.

Where is the toolbox located?

I would like to test out the new tools as mentioned in the blog post. I'm running ArcGIS 10.2.1.

Comment: I've tweeted at the main ESRI account and [ESRI Defense](https://twitter.com/EsriDefense), no response yet.

Comment: Can you send me the FMV.tbx ? I am having no luck getting it from MyESRI. My account is not set up yet and the customer care portal is MIA.

Comment: @MDHald Customer Care portal is now [my.esri.com](my.esri.com). The FMV addin + gp toolbox is under the Additional Products section of the Desktop downloads. If you are not in the US you will need to contact your local ESRI distributor for a licence. Also, the point of my question is to find out where the toolbox is installed.

Comment: Hey, I downloaded and installed the add-in. I ran into the same problems!!! so I contacted ESRI Support and someone is picking away at it. At a high level so far, we have troubleshooted adding the add-in manually using the add-in manager. Additionally, we have attempted standard install. Neither were successful so the ESRI support is looking into the problem. As soon as I get an update I will update here.

Comment: @MDHald That would be useful thanks. I really have had no luck on my side.

Comment: @MDHald Did you manage to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step-by-step answer can be found on pages 11 - 12 of the tutorial pdf found in the [template](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e8c47c6b4d634b6aba6a5a2e3a9e16a9). A new toolbox has to be created manually, with the tools added from the main tools list.

Answer (score 1):

Running ArcMap 10.4 here - just "installed" the FMV Add-In by utilizing the Add-In Manager, which is under Customize. You don't really install the Add-In, or any sort of a Toolbox that's been mentioned here as FMV is ultimately available to you via a Toolbar, much like the Georeferencing or Draw Toolbars, for example.

First, though, you can only access the 12.5mb zipped folder from ESRI if you've been given access to it under Downloads, which is in the My Organizations tab in my.esri.com.

Installing can be done by:

- just double-clicking the *.esriaddin file, and then restarting ArcMap; or
- pointing your Add-In Manager to the folder where you've chosen to unzip the downloaded folder from Esri.

Comment: An easier way to install an AddIn should be to just double-click the `*.esriaddin` file, and then restart ArcMap.  That takes care of all the unzipping etc.

Comment: Woh! Even better! I did not see that, so thanks for adding!